# SQL Server with Cross Join Unpivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-normalization, unpivot, cross-apply

I have a unique cross apply.  I have a table that looks like this.

ID[image]

What I would like to see to see is if this can be split into 2 rows and 4 columns.
I would like to split the SUB together and the APP together.

```
ClaimID === SUB Cost === APP Cost === Cost Type
109508  === 51.86    === 0.00     === "Parts"
109508  === 318.08   === 0.00     === "Labor"
```

This allows the table to have a simple one line for SUB vs APP cost for each category.  I would really appreciate some help with this. As a side note, I was able to do this where this 1 row turned into 4 rows with the SUB and APP each being on separate lines(one row for each column), but then we lose ability to compare SUB vs APP on the row.

Comment: Although you are rearranging your data, this has nothing to do with any of the things people refer to by "normalization".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `Cross Apply` to *unpivot* the data

```
SELECT ClaimId,
       [Sub Cost],
       [App Cost],
       [Cost Type]
FROM   yourtable
       CROSS apply (VALUES (SUB_AllParts,APP_AllParts, 'Parts'),
                           (SUB_AllLabor,APP_AllLabor,'Labor')) 
                           tc ([Sub Cost], [App Cost], [Cost Type])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select claimid
        ,sub_allparts as 'sub cost'
        ,app_allparts as 'app cost'
        ,'"Parts"' as 'Cost Type'  
        from claim 
union all
select claimid
        ,sub_alllabor as 'sub cost'
        ,app_alllabor as 'app cost'
        ,'"Labor"' as 'Cost Type' 
         from claim
```